# Put GWT MVP views in their own file in contrast to an inline interface

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

Most of the gwt mvp tutorials show the view interface declared as an inline interface in the presenter class. Is there a good reason for doing that or is creating a separate file for the View interface a better choice or does it just not matter (I know it doesn't matter for the compiler).

```
public ItemPresenter {
 ...    
 public interface MyView<> {
   public void setName(..);      
 }
 ...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's no technical need to use an inner interface. It will definitely work with separate compilation units.

I personally prefer inner interfaces as the presenter together with the view interface define the contract how these two communicate with each other.

Another reason for me is naming. Think about ItemPresenter & ItemView vs ItemPresenter & ItemPresenter.View. For me the latter is more intuitive as the View is defined by the presenter itself.

And the last reason is copy&past. Yes, that's right :)
For presenters/views as well as Events with inner handler interface, I have empty copy&paste templates in my workspace. With the inner interface you won't have trouble with imports when copying the template.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what you do. It is just to bring things closer together.